# Excel VBA - To find the last friday date of the previous month

Tags: excel, vba

Hi as I'm new to excel macro's i have some difficulties to write the syntax.

I want to display the last Friday date of the previous month in a cell.

If i run a report in the month of December say (22/12/2017) it should display the last Friday date of the month of November (i.e: 24/11/2017) in a cell say A2.

Could someone help me on this please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

An Excel formula to achieve this would be

```
=NOW()-DAY(NOW())+1-WEEKDAY(NOW()-DAY(NOW()),15)
```

An equivalent VBA formula would be

```
Range("A2").Value = CDate(Now() - Day(Now()) + 1 - Weekday(Now() - Day(Now()), vbFriday))
```

Comment: it works perfect.thank you so much.